Solidity smart contract not compiling in python
I am trying to use the following to compile and deploy a smart contract.
The last line comes with the error mentioned below.
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from solcx import compile_files, install_solc, compile_source
 
caller = "0xb934c******f832860DBD"
private_key = "1d7bb4b13a*******80cb885336726f"
 
url = 'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/8af*********4714b5d'
 
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(url))
 
path_solidity = "/h********ckend-dlh/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol"
 
install_solc("0.8.20")
 
# Compile Solidity
compiled_sol = compile_files([path_solidity])
 

Error msg
/bin/python3 /home/tgrandjean/Data/oasees/issuer-backend-dlh/deployNFT.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home****issuer-backend-dlh/deployNFT.py", line 16, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_files([path_solidity])
  File "/home/*****/lib/python3.8/site-packages/solcx/main.py", line 216, in compile_files
    return _compile_combined_json(
  File "*****/lib/python3.8/site-packages/solcx/main.py", line 277, in _compile_combined_json
    combined_json = _get_combined_json_outputs(solc_binary)
  File "*****.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/solcx/main.py", line 242, in _get_combined_json_outputs
    help_str = wrapper.solc_wrapper(solc_binary=solc_binary, help=True)[0].split("\n")
  File "*****l/lib/python3.8/site-packages/solcx/wrapper.py", line 158, in solc_wrapper
    raise SolcError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcError: An error occurred during execution
> command: `/usr/bin/solc --help -`
> return code: `0`
> stdout:
solc, the Solidity commandline compiler.

The compiler version is on line with the content of the solidity code.
If I try compile the solidity code using "solc" from the command line it works well !
Can somebody help ?
Thanks
